# Optimizing DB inserts in .NET parallel processing

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, npoco, amazon-ses

I have to send a lot of emails using AWS SES (say 10,000 per job). Found [a great blog](http://michaeldimoudis.com/blog/2013/5/25/reliably-and-speedily-send-mass-emails-via-amazon-ses-in-c) on how to do so in parallel, now have a question on how to write the send transactional data to a DB.  I'm using the npoco ORM and InsertBulk, which from my cursory look opens a connection and inserts by iterating through each poco, then closes the connection. Short of opening, writing and closing per send, this is a step up.  My thought here is to keep DB operations to a minimum, but I should write to the DB every 50 or so email sends, in case of a server or job interruption, the job could later pick up where it left off without sending duplicates, etc.

So I started using ConcurrentBag, thread locking, converting to list, sending that list to npoco to insert, etc. Tested very limitedly and it works. But I'm sure it's not the proper way to go about it, and I have no confidence I'm using threading appropriately here. What are the suggestions in this scenario? Would it be better or feasible to pass the concurrentbag to npoco for the insert, some other insert method?

```
 var bag = new ConcurrentBag<EmailSent>();
    Parallel.ForEach(recipients.AsParallel(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxParallelEmails },
          recipient =>
           {
         var response = client.SendEmail(request);
          bag.Add(new EmailSent() { JobId = jobId, MessageId = response.MessageId});
       }
    lock (syncRoot) 
        {
             count++;
             if (count % 50 == 0 || count == recipients.Count) 
              {
               var list = new List<EmailSent>();
                 while (!bag.IsEmpty)
                  {
                   EmailSent email;
                     if (bag.TryTake(out email))
                      {
                        list.Add(email);

                      }

               }
            repo.InsertBulk<EmailSent>(list);
       }
});
```

Comment: What if you generate a unique ID for each email so that it isn't duplicated in the database and also know where it was left off the last time.. and I am sure inserting a record in a database should be pretty fast ..so inserting per 50 emails sent should complete quickly in a single thread..

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for optimizations, one is to use [table valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) for your inserts, so that you send multiple records to your stored procedure instead of calling it once for each insert.

On your SQL server you define the parameter type, which looks much like defining a table. (Most samples are from the link above.)

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CategoryTableType AS TABLE
( CategoryID int, CategoryName nvarchar(50) )
```

Then you add a parameter of that type to your insert procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateCategories 
(@tvpNewCategories dbo.CategoryTableType READONLY)
```

Within your stored procedure you can select from that parameter as if was a table variable.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName)
SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName FROM @tvpNewCategories AS nc;
```

What's nice about this is that you can perform all of the inserts as a single operation.

On the application side you would create a DataTable that corresponds to the table type you defined.Then you populate the table with the records you want to insert.

Finally, when calling the procedure, you add a parameter with your DataTable as its value, specify `SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured` and 'TypeName' is the name of the table type.

```
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
"@tvpNewCategories", yourDataTable);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";
```

If you worked with SQL server before 2008 you know that we did some weird things to pass multiple records to a procedure, like concatenating strings or sending and parsing XML. This is much easier and cuts way down on the number of individual stored procedure calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ConcurrentQueue` instead of `ConcurrentBag`. You don't have to worry about locking anything when you add to the queue or take items out. If you want to save records in batches of *n* you can just continually `TryDeqeueue` and add the dequeued items to a collection until either the collection count is *n* or `TryDequeue` returns `false`, meaning that there's nothing left in the queue.